# How to create a UITableView with custom picker-like edit mode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In a regular `UITableView` in edit mode you drag the cell into the position you want the cell to be in and the other cells can pop into place. I want to create a `UITableView` edit mode where you select a cell and it is held in the center as you scroll the tableview to move the selected item, holding the selected item in the center with the table cells moving around the center selected cell.

A valid 'bounty worthy' answer will require a minimally working example that holds a selected cell in the center of the table and can be moved by swiping the table up and down. Including the edge cases of first and last position in the table. Alternatively, you can outline the key points of what you think would work and if they lead me in the right direction, then you'll get the bounty.

### Update 1

I have established a project called [PickerTableView](https://github.com/palmerc/PickerTableView/tree/develop) on GitHub. Working on the develop branch. Selection is working and I'm working on subclassing TableView to handle the movement of the cell on scroll. Finding a working solution before me will still earn the bounty.

### Further Clarification

Based upon a comment, I'll provide some ASCII art.

#### The TableView

```
|==========|
|      Next|
|==========|
|          |
|----------|
|          |
|----------|
|          |
|----------|
|          |
|----------|
|          |
|==========|
```

#### Select a cell, then tap Next

```
|==========|
|      Next|
|==========|
|          |
|----------|
|          |
|----------|
|         X|
|----------|
|          |
|----------|
|          |
|==========|
```

#### Tableview Editing Mode

```
|=============|
|         Done|
|=============|
|             |
|-------------|
|             |
|-------------|
| This cell is|
| Highlighted |
| and locked  |
| in place    |
|-------------|
|             |
|-------------|   
|             |
|=============|
```

As you scroll the tableview the cells that were not selected flow around the selected cell while the selected cell stays in the middle.

Comment: can be done with a stock tableview quite easily

Comment: Do you mean something that resembles a picker view?

Comment: It could be argued to be something like a picker view. However the cell you Are moving doesn't move from the center and the other cells move past

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get how you want it to work...but...I have an App in the App Store where you can drag/drop the table view cells in edit mode to re-order the items (it is called Six Things).  If you take a look and it works like you are thinking, I'll share how it works.  **NOTE:** In Six Things, when you press the top of group and enter edit mode, you can drag the item and the table scrolls when you hit the top/bottom so you can drop it into any of the sublists.

Comment: @Daij-Djan based upon my work so far, I don't believe a 'stock' tableview will do it. You're definitely going to have to subclass UITableView and manage moving cells manually and I'm still not sure you'll get a professional result.

Comment: I'd suggest using UICollectionView for this instead of UITableView.  You can provide two different `UICollectionViewLayout` objects depending on whether you're in "editing" mode or not.  Trying to get UITableView to flow cells around the selected cell seems like an exercise in futility.

Comment: Such an unconventional UI--can I ask what's the use case?

Comment: The designer designed it. :) Our design team feels this is the best way in  dealing with a large number of items that might have to be reordered. It has to do with the postal service and mailbox route ordering.

Comment: I think a good way to do this would be to make 3 table views. (temporarily) One for the upper cells, one for the lower cells, and another to contain the "floating" cell. When either the upper or lower table view is scrolled, scroll the other scroll view a corresponding amount. Cells will seem to enter the floating cell from one side or the other while simultaneously exiting the other side. You may not need the center table view--it's so that cell will have a container. Not sure cells can work outside of table views.

Comment: Actually, we already tried that and we didn't get it to work well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my answer is the best at this time I will provide my own answer.

I have established a project called [PickerTableView](https://github.com/palmerc/PickerTableView/tree/develop) on GitHub. Working on the develop branch. This project uses Cocoapods for the dependencies. Selection is working and I've subclassed TableView to handle the movement of the cell on scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be acceptable if the selected cell was not really a cell but a separate `UIView` (that could be made to look like a cell)? If so, you could do something like this:

1. When a cell is tapped remove it from the table and show the cell-like `UIView` over the table.
2. Reposition cells as they scroll by responding to `-scrollViewDidScroll:`.
3. When the Done button is tapped, reinsert the item into the table and hide the cell-like `UIView`

To see it in action, I've created a UIViewController subclass for you to test:

`PickerTableViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PickerTableViewController : UIViewController

@end

@interface SelectedItemView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UILabel *label;

@end
```

`PickerTableViewController.m`

```
#import "PickerTableViewController.h"

@interface PickerTableViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *button;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *tableViewContainer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SelectedItemView *selectedItemView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;
@property (nonatomic, getter = isPicking) BOOL picking;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *selectedItem;

@end

@implementation PickerTableViewController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // generate random cell contents
        NSInteger countItems = 20;
        self.items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:countItems];
        for (int i = 0; i < countItems; i++) {
            [self.items addObject:@(arc4random() % 100)];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.button setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(stopPicking) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.button.enabled = self.isPicking;
    [self.view addSubview:self.button];

    // use a container for easy alignment of selected item view to center of table
    _tableViewContainer = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:_tableViewContainer];

    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.tableViewContainer addSubview:self.tableView];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    CGFloat const buttonHeight = 100.0f;
    CGRect const buttonFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, buttonHeight);
    self.button.frame = buttonFrame;

    CGRect tableFrame = self.view.bounds;
    tableFrame.origin.y += buttonHeight;
    tableFrame.size.height -= buttonHeight;
    self.tableViewContainer.frame = tableFrame;
    self.tableView.frame = self.tableViewContainer.bounds;

    // allow table to scroll to first and last row
    CGFloat selectedItemViewY = self.selectedItemView.center.y;
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(selectedItemViewY, 0.0f, selectedItemViewY, 0.0f);
}

#pragma mark - Custom

- (SelectedItemView *)selectedItemView
{
    if (!_selectedItemView) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.rowHeight);
        _selectedItemView = [[SelectedItemView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        _selectedItemView.center = CGPointMake(self.tableView.bounds.size.width * 0.5f, self.tableView.bounds.size.height * 0.5f);
        _selectedItemView.hidden = YES;
        [self.tableViewContainer addSubview:_selectedItemView];
    }
    return _selectedItemView;
}

- (void)startPickingForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if (self.isPicking) {
        return;
    }
    self.picking = YES;

    // update tableview
    self.selectedItem = [self.items objectAtIndex:index];
    [self.items removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self repositionCells];

    // update views
    self.selectedItemView.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.selectedItem];
    self.selectedItemView.hidden = NO;
    self.button.enabled = YES;
}

- (void)stopPicking
{
    if (!self.isPicking) {
        return;
    }
    self.picking = NO;

    // calculate new index for item
    NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"row" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sds = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sd];
    NSArray *indexPaths = [[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sds];
    NSInteger selectedItemIndex = NSNotFound;
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths) {
        if ([self isCellAtIndexPathBelowSelectedItemView:indexPath]) {
            selectedItemIndex = indexPath.row;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (selectedItemIndex == NSNotFound) {
        selectedItemIndex = self.items.count;
    }

    // update tableview
    [self.items insertObject:self.selectedItem atIndex:selectedItemIndex];
    self.selectedItem = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    // update views
    self.selectedItemView.hidden = YES;
    self.button.enabled = NO;
}

- (BOOL)isCellAtIndexPathBelowSelectedItemView:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat yInTable = indexPath.row * self.tableView.rowHeight;
    CGFloat yInContainer = yInTable - self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
    return yInContainer > self.selectedItemView.frame.origin.y;
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.isPicking) {
        [self stopPicking];
    }

    // scroll position seems to be confused... UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle doesn't work?
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

    [self startPickingForItemAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (self.isPicking) {
        [self repositionCells];
    }
}

- (void)repositionCells
{
    CGFloat tableOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
    NSArray *indexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    CGFloat selectedItemViewY = self.selectedItemView.frame.origin.y;
    CGFloat const bufferHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight; // adjust to liking
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        CGRect cellFrame = cell.frame;

        CGFloat cellYInTable = indexPath.row * self.tableView.rowHeight;
        cellFrame.origin.y = cellYInTable;

        CGFloat cellYInContainer = cellYInTable - tableOffset;
        if (cellYInContainer <= selectedItemViewY) {
            cellFrame.origin.y -= bufferHeight;
        } else {
            cellFrame.origin.y += bufferHeight;
        }
        cell.frame = cellFrame;
    }
}

@end

@interface SelectedItemView ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *label;

@end

@implementation SelectedItemView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        _label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:_label];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.label.frame = self.bounds;
}

@end
```

Comment: This idea is very similar to what I'm doing in the cited GitHub above. However, the central issue is making the cells snap/flow around the centered item. I currently attach the UIImageView of the transformed cell to the cell.

Comment: OK, I've found that the `-scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate call is a good place to get the other cells to flow around the centered item. Have you had a chance to test out this code above? I couldn't get your github repo to build as there were some missing libraries. I can see issues trying to keep a specific UITableViewCell in place as  when you scroll, the tableview will want to remove the cell and recycle it... (i think!)

Answer (score 2):

when u select a cell in edit mode. Do these:

1. Scroll the cell to center position.
2. use `renderInContext` to cut out an image of the moved cell.
3. put the image in an imageView, and add it to the tableView's superview. In accordance to center position, relative to tableView's superView.
4. after that u are free to scroll around the table. Just delete the selected cell beforehand, to avoid duplicacy in UI.
5. On pressing next. Insert a row in the desired position, with the desired data and remove the added ImageView.
6. Animations involved are entirely left to ur discretion :D

Cheers have fun.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. If you check my GitHub repo (develop branch) cited above, I'm doing that. Really the issue is making the selected cell stick in the center and having the cells snap around that cell as you scroll up and down. So item 6 is the crux of the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of something that does what you want (that is, after some adjustments). I think it's pretty minimal code-wise:

https://github.com/nielsbot/funny-tables

(For your use case, you would reveal `centerTableView` and `bottomTableView` when you enter edit mode.)